# Reset password of Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook

We developed an OCR but we do not remember password of Jupyter and we tried to resest it via this command "jupyter notebook password" in terminal it works but password is not updated, so i am here for someone help me to solve this issue. Thanks

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHaLL.png)

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me after an upgrade. You can simply erase your jupyter configuration files and issue (again!):

```
jupyter notebook password
```

This will generate a new hash in your configuration file that you can use for logging in.